# Terminating an application when closing the window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm a little bit new to Objective-c with xCode, and I would like to know something. Is there a way to terminate an application when the red circle in the left of the window is clicked? Like on the calculator.

Comment: Make your question more clear. Are you talking about a cocoa application? Specify the appropriate tag.

Comment: @Rakesh Yes, a Cocoa application. Sorry for any unclarity

Comment: Np. You have a working solution below. You can accept it as answer ,if you feel its good enough. Good luck.

Comment: +1 for question on osx :) . I want to build SO database powerfull enough even for osx. That is why I upvote for osx problem.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thanks :) OS X is truly awesome.

Comment: Try This.. -(IBAction)closeProgram:(id)sender{ exit(0); }

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Yes you can do with Mac OSX applications**.

You need to implement this method in your AppDelegate class

```
 - (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why down vote? Targeting me?? I got three in short span of time, and then one was reverted.

Comment: +1 from my side but this one is really nice answer, i mean like most of those one liner which go hight in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

If you want terminate the app when closing the window. Please implement the following appdelegate method.

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender
    {
        return YES;
    }
```

If you want do not terminate your app, just set the return "NO".

I hope that your problem will be resolved with this solution.